# Hiding a division using CSS

Tags: css, hide, html, blogger

I am trying to remove a division but I am not able to remove the `<div>` tag. So I wanted to know if I can hide a division by adding some css codes on the page. The division I am trying to hide is `<div id="views" class="menu">.... </div>`

Any help?

Comment: If u  using jquery , then $('#views').hide() on event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS to your page or CSS file:

```
div#views { display:none; }
```

If you require the div to still occupy the space on the page, use the following instead:

```
div#views { visibility:hidden; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#views
{
  display: none;
}
```

in your css